# How to display a image using Templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating one app using following two url's , homepage.html and detail.html

I want to display primary_image in homepage.html with primary_image as a link.

Also, I want to display both primary_image & secondary_Image in a detail.html

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length = 256)
    author_Detail = models.CharField("Author" , max_length = 128)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Published Date")
    primary_image = models.ImageField("Main Image ",upload_to = "static/uploadedImg/main",)
    secondary_Image = models.ImageField("Sub Image",upload_to = "static/uploadedImg/sub",)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

articles.html

```
<div id = "randomArticle">
    <div id = "randommainImage">
         <a href = "{{random_object.id}}"><img id = "randomImage"
              src = "{{random_object.primary_image}}" width ="800" height = "300" alt = "{{random_object.title}}"></a>
</div>
```

I am able to save uploaded images in the following path "media/static/uploadedImg/main" but I am not able to access in template.

Also I am checking in firebug its displaying the following path "/media/static/uploadedImg/main/home_category_image01.jpg"

Also the following obtained in server 
"GET /media/static/uploadedImg/main/home_category_image01
.jpg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2186

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show what you've been doing so far in your templates?

Comment: Have you tried something like `News.objects.primary_image.url` in your templates in this case `homepage.html`, to get the `primary_image` url ?

Comment: @Lorenzo Pena : Display images and title clickable  {% block content %}
{% for model in models %}
<h2><a href = "{{model.id}}">{{model.title}}</a><h2>
<p>{{model.date|date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the loop:

```
<img src="{{ model.primary_image.url }}" alt="{{ model.title }}">
<img src="{{ model.secondary_image.url }}" alt="{{ model.title }}">
```